# Optimizing Join between a very small and a very large table

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `TBL_REPORT` (
  `ID_TBL_REPORT` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `INDEX_NAME` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `INDEX_VALUE` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `FK_TBL_REPORT_PROXY` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `PAYLOAD` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `OPERATION` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ERROR` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `SERVER` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `DATA` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_TBL_REPORT`),
  KEY `TBL_INTER_TBL_INTER_PROXY_FK` (`FK_TBL_REPORT_PROXY`),
  KEY `IX_INDEX_NAME` (`INDEX_NAME`),
  KEY `IX_INDEX_VALUE` (`INDEX_VALUE`),
  KEY `IX_DATA` (`DATA`),
  CONSTRAINT `TBL_INTER_TBL_INTER_PROXY_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`FK_TBL_REPORT_PROXY`) REFERENCES `TBL_REPORT_PROXY` (`ID_TBL_REPORT_PROXY`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4769095 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `TBL_REPORT_PROXY` (
  `ID_TBL_REPORT_PROXY` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PROXY` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `SERVICE_GROUP` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID_TBL_REPORT_PROXY`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The fields `INDEX_NAME`, `INDEX_VALUE` and `DATA` has indexes created.

The first table represents a call to a service in a SOA Bus, and the second table represents the service attributes.
The first can contains more than 100.000.000 rows and the second about 100 rows.

My goal is to select filtering by some field, and paginating by `limit n,10`. The fields that can be used to filter are `PROXY`, `INDEX_NAME`, `ERROR` and `DATA`.

For example, if the user wants to see the first page filtering by `PROXY`, the query is:

```
select R.ID_TBL_REPORT, R.INDEX_NAME, R.INDEX_VALUE, R.ERROR, R.DATA, P.PROXY, P.SERVICE_GROUP 
    from TBL_REPORT R, TBL_REPORT_PROXY P
        where P.PROXY = 'MyProxy' 
        and R.FK_TBL_REPORT_PROXY = P.ID_TBL_REPORT_PROXY 
        limit 1,10;
```

This works well and the result is shown very fast.
However, the results need to be ordered by the last inserted rows:

```
select R.ID_TBL_REPORT, R.INDEX_NAME, R.INDEX_VALUE, R.ERROR, R.DATA, P.PROXY, P.SERVICE_GROUP 
    from TBL_REPORT R, TBL_REPORT_PROXY P
        where P.PROXY = 'MyProxy' 
        and R.FK_TBL_REPORT_PROXY = P.ID_TBL_REPORT_PROXY 
        order by R.DATA desc  -- ordering by the the last first
        limit 1,10;
```

This query is so big and slow that the mysql shows this error, and no result rows:

```
ERROR 126 (HY000): Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_52d8_0.MYI'; try to repair it
```

So, how to optimize this tables/queries to obtain the results?

**EDIT**

```
MySQL [report]> explain select R.ID_TBL_REPORT, R.INDEX_NAME, R.INDEX_VALUE, R.ERROR, R.DATA, P.PROXY, P.SERVICE_GROUP from TBL_REPORT R, TBL_REPORT_PROXY P where P.PROXY = 'MyProxy' and R.FK_TBL_REPORT_PROXY = P.ID_TBL_REPORT_PROXY limit 1,10;
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                | key                          | key_len | ref                               | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | P     | ALL  | PRIMARY                      | NULL                         | NULL    | NULL                              |      5 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | R     | ref  | TBL_INTER_TBL_INTER_PROXY_FK | TBL_INTER_TBL_INTER_PROXY_FK | 8       | wso2_report.P.ID_TBL_REPORT_PROXY | 262154 |             |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MySQL [report]> explain select R.ID_TBL_REPORT, R.INDEX_NAME, R.INDEX_VALUE, R.ERROR, R.DATA, P.PROXY, P.SERVICE_GROUP from TBL_REPORT R, TBL_REPORT_PROXY P where P.PROXY = 'MyProxy' and R.FK_TBL_REPORT_PROXY = P.ID_TBL_REPORT_PROXY order by DATA desc limit 1,10;
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                | key                          | key_len | ref                               | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | P     | ALL  | PRIMARY                      | NULL                         | NULL    | NULL                              |      5 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | R     | ref  | TBL_INTER_TBL_INTER_PROXY_FK | TBL_INTER_TBL_INTER_PROXY_FK | 8       | wso2_report.P.ID_TBL_REPORT_PROXY | 262154 |                                              |
+----+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+-----------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**EDIT 2**

The "explains" of the two queries proposed by @RickJames, respectively:

```
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TBL_REPORT       | index | NULL          | IX_DATA | 4       | NULL |    2 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TBL_REPORT_PROXY | ALL   | PRIMARY       | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |    5 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+-------------+

+----+-------------+------------------+------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type | possible_keys                | key                          | key_len | ref                                              | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+------------------+------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TBL_REPORT_PROXY | ALL  | PRIMARY                      | NULL                         | NULL    | NULL                                             |      5 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TBL_REPORT       | ref  | TBL_INTER_TBL_INTER_PROXY_FK | TBL_INTER_TBL_INTER_PROXY_FK | 8       | wso2_report.TBL_REPORT_PROXY.ID_TBL_REPORT_PROXY | 263813 |                                 |
+----+-------------+------------------+------+------------------------------+------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: Do you have an index on `(FK_TBL_REPORT_PROXY)`? Show us the `explain` output, for both queries. You probably going to need an index on `(FK_TBL_REPORT_PROXY, DATA)` for this query.

Comment: @ypercube edited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong interpretation of the error.

You had a power failure (or some other crash).  You are using MyISAM (you should use InnoDB).  Those caused the "Incorrect key file for table".

```
CHECK TABLE TBL_REPORT R;
CHECK TABLE TBL_REPORT_PROXY;
```

If either says to "repair", then perform `REPAIR TABLE`.

If that does not work, look at this value:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir';
```

Does that refer to a separate filesystem?  Is that filesystem small?  Perhaps you ran out of disk space *in that filesystem* (/tmp)?  If so, consider not putting tmpdir in it.  (Actually, I would expect a different error message if you ran out of disk space.)

*Please* use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.  I can't tell what indexes you have.  You need one starting with `FK_TBL_REPORT_PROXY` and/or one starting with `DATA`.

The optimizer wants to start with the smaller table, especially since you have a WHERE clause restricting the rows there.

I have two suggestions; either or both *might* help:

This version tries to force it to use your index starting with DATA, which would let it quit after 10 rows:

```
select  R.ID_TBL_REPORT, R.INDEX_NAME, R.INDEX_VALUE, R.ERROR,
        R.DATA, P.PROXY, P.SERVICE_GROUP
    from  TBL_REPORT R FORCE INDEX(DATA)
    JOIN  TBL_REPORT_PROXY P IGNORE INDEX(PROXY)
         ON R.FK_TBL_REPORT_PROXY = P.ID_TBL_REPORT_PROXY
    where  P.PROXY = 'MyProxy'
    order by  R.DATA desc -- ordering by the the last first
    limit  1,10;
```

This version switches to `HAVING` in an attempt to trick it into not starting with the PROXY table:

```
select  R.ID_TBL_REPORT, R.INDEX_NAME, R.INDEX_VALUE, R.ERROR,
        R.DATA, P.PROXY, P.SERVICE_GROUP
    from  TBL_REPORT R
    JOIN  TBL_REPORT_PROXY P
         ON R.FK_TBL_REPORT_PROXY = P.ID_TBL_REPORT_PROXY
    HAVING  P.PROXY = 'MyProxy'
    order by  R.DATA desc -- ordering by the the last first
    limit  1,10;
```

(I switched from comma-JOIN to the preferred explicit JOIN.)

Please run `EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...;` then `SHOW WARNINGS;` on each of them, and show us the outputs.

I have a [blog on the evils of pagination using OFFSET and LIMIT](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).  It includes a much more efficient alternative.  However, you must first get past the immediate problem.

Comment: Nice!!! The tables showed no erros. However, your first query forcing the index of DATA works like a charm. Thank you very much!

Comment: And I will read your article about the pagination.

Comment: So the HAVING solution did not help?  I was hoping to see the EXPLAINs and WARNINGs.  The WARNING is how the Optimizer rewrote the query.  It may have turned the HAVING back into a WHERE.

Comment: Explains added! There's no "warnings" for both. The first appears to be better.